# Why does this pip call succeed in Makefile but not via command line?

Tags: python, pip

I ran across this in a Makefile recently:

```
develop:
      pip install "file://`pwd`#egg=MyProject"
```

This works fine when called with `make develop` but when I call the same command via the command-line it errors out "`No such file or directory: /home/slack/tmp/myproject#egg=MyProject'`"

Why does this work when it's in a Makefile but not called explicitly from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file://` bit is telling pip to install from a local resource. The `pwd` command tells it the local resource is in the current directory, and then it tacks on what the egg is called.

I assume that this make file sets up the egg so that the naming convention holds for this lookup, and that there may be some default variables or commands in the makefile that adjust it.

Comment: Yeah, I get that part about the file:// and pwd.  The lines I have above are the only lines in the Makefile.

Comment: @seth Those are the only lines in the makefile? Hmmm, are you running the pip command from the same directory as the makefile? Make and/or pip may be setting some defaults that are different from your user settings, or your shell may have different env settings.

Comment: Nailed it.  Different versions of pip. The new weirdness is `which pip` matched in the Makefile and the shell but `pip --version` outputs different results twixt the two. Thanks for reminding me to always check environment.T